# Why doesn't dir with variables copy in a text file?

Tags: windows, batch-file

I am trying to create a txt with the result of a dir command using a variable.

When I execute the command `dir /b "Pr?ctica %var%"`, having set var to a value before it works just as expected (in cmd). But I am trying to do exaclty the same in a batch, like this: `dir /b "Pr?ctica %2" >> temp.txt` but the file is empty, when it should not!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does `%2` contain quotes? If so, this will lead to a syntax error. Use `%~2` to strip the quotes.

```
dir /b "Pr?ctica %~2" >> temp.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Not really enough information.

What are you supplying as `%2`?

For instance, I have a set of files

```
ZZQ9 WITH SPACES.BAT
ZZQ9 WITH%PCNT%K.BAT
ZZQ9 WITH&AMPERS.BAT
ZZQ9 WITH,COMMAK.BAT
ZZQ9 WITH;SEMITK.BAT
ZZQ9 WITH^CARETK.BAT
```

Executing

```
batchfilename dummy with
```

where batchfilename.bat contains

```
dir /b "zz?9 %2"
```

produces no output (because there are no files "zz?9 with" but

```
dir /b "zz?9 %2*"
```

Happily lists the files as expected.

OTOH, executing

```
set GROO=with&batchfilename dummy groo&set groo=
```

would attempt to list "zz?9 groo" or "zz?9 groo*" files, which do not exist, but

```
CALL DIR /b "ZZ?9 %%%2%%*"
```

and

```
SETLOCAL enabledelayedexpansion
CALL DIR /b "ZZ?9 !%2!*"
```

both listed the targets correctly.